# How to get the selected row from a link to a new page

Tags: php, mysql

Hello what I want is to get the same `$typeValue` which I am displaying in a message and then display the data.

In the first page the code that I am display the message with a specific `$typeValue` is the below

```
//ALERT SYSTEM    
    $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT username, typeValue FROM sensors WHERE (sensorValue < min OR sensorValue > max) AND doctorStatus='0'");
    $query3 = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM sensors WHERE (sensorValue < min OR sensorValue > max) AND doctorStatus='0'");
    //$row3 = mysql_fetch_array($query3);  
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query2))
    {
        while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($query3))
        {
            $p1 = mysql_num_rows(queryMysql("SELECT * FROM connected
            WHERE username='$row3[0]' AND friend='$username'"));
            $p2 = mysql_num_rows(queryMysql("SELECT * FROM connected
            WHERE username='$username' AND friend='$row3[0]'"));
            if (($p1 + $p2) > 1)
            {
                $alert_message= " <b><font color=red><p align='center'>User " . $row['username'] . " Has A Health Problem with his/her ".$row['typeValue']."</font></b>";
                $link_address = "health_problem.php?view=".$row['username']."&typevalue=".$row['typeValue'];
            ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $link_address;?>"> <?php echo $alert_message; ?> </a>
            <?php
            }
        } 

    }
```

And the code of the other page which I want to display this data

```
<?php

/**
 * @author Nick Bourlai
 * @copyright 2015
 */

include_once 'header.php';


$result = queryMysql("SELECT * FROM patient WHERE username='$username'");
if(mysql_num_rows($result))
{
    $query = "UPDATE sensors SET status='1' WHERE status ='0' AND username='$username'";
    mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
}
else
{
    $query = "UPDATE sensors SET doctorStatus='1' WHERE doctorStatus ='0' AND username='$view'";
    mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
}

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','smogi','project');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
$view = ($_GET['view']);
$username2 =$_SESSION['username'];
$typeValue = ($_GET['typeValue']); 
$sql="SELECT typeValue,unit,sensorValue,datetime FROM sensors WHERE username='$view' AND typeValue='$typeValue'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
echo $view;
echo $typeValue;
echo "<table>
<tr>


</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr> <b>Type: </b>";
    echo stripslashes($row['typeValue']) . "<br/><b>Unit: </b>";
    echo stripslashes($row['unit']) . "<br/><b>Value: </b>";
    echo stripslashes($row['sensorValue']) . "<br/><b>Date: </b>";
    echo stripslashes($row['datetime']) . "<br/>";
    echo "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------";
    echo "<br/></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

?>
```

So what I want is to get from the clicked link the specific row and display the data of this row in the other page.

Comment: for one thing, you're mixing `mysql_` with `mysqli_` functions; that doesn't work.

Comment: @Fred-ii- but can this create the problem?

Comment: yepper, and big time. they do not intermix.

Comment: @Fred-ii- ok i will remove the `mysql_query` just to see if it change something in the result

Comment: @Fred-ii- no, nothing change :-/

Comment: plus, make sure that if you're going to stick with `mysqli_` that your connection is `mysqli_` and not `mysql_`.

Comment: you also need to place your connection at the top of your script(s).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78363/discussion-between-dogface-and-fred-ii).

Comment: `$_GET['view']` is the username var to use on `health_problem.php`

Comment: @Dagon view and username are something different

Comment: .. `health_problem.php?view=".$row['username'].` .. suggests other wise

Comment: @Dagon same thing , still i am not getting my data

Comment: @Fred-ii- by mistake i switch my language in the keyboard and you answer was correct , about the small V in the word please write it as an answer in order to accept it

Comment: @DogFace it has been done, glad to hear it was resolved, cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *@Fred-ii- by mistake i switch my language in the keyboard and you answer was correct , about the small V in the word please write it as an answer in order to accept it*

- As per requested:

Your GET value is using an lowercase v in the URL
`health_problem.php?view=magda&typevalue=Temperature`, rather than an uppercase V in relation to `typeValue` in the GET array `$_GET['typeValue']`

- `health_problem.php?view=magda&typeValue=Temperature`
- Variables are case-sensitive.

Plus, on top of what has already been stated by myself in comments, that different MySQL APIs do not intermix with each other. Use the same MySQL API from connection to query.

---

**Footnotes:**

- Consider using [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

Answer (score 1):

PHP variables and array keys are case sensitive. This line in your 2nd script

```
$typeValue = ($_GET['typeValue']);
```

should be

```
$typeValue = ($_GET['typevalue']);
```